# Getting a list of text channels from guild id discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributes

How would I be able to convert `nukeguild` from a plain ID to something I could extract .text_channels attribute from? Am I overlooking anything or is there an easier alternative?

Here is the snippet from my code:

```
async def guildNuke():
    nukeguild = input("Nuke guild ID: ")
    with nukeguild.text_channels as channelids:
        for items in channelids:
            print(items)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `get_guild`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)



@ bot.event
async def on_ready():
    id = int(input("enter guild ID\n> "))
    channelIds = bot.get_guild(id).text_channels
    for items in channelIds:
        print(items)

bot.run("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Please note:

- This will only work with guilds that the bot is in.
- I noticed some issues when using an older version of py-cord: if you get an error relating to "news", try updating.